# Comparing owners and permissions of content of two folders?

Tags: linux, files

How to to compare owners and permissions of content of two folders? Is there something like `diff` command which compare recursively two folders and display owner and permissions differences?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution, as with all things, is a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Find;

my $directory1 = '/tmp/temp1';
my $directory2 = '/tmp/temp2';

find(\&hashfiles, $directory1);

sub hashfiles {
  my $file1 = $File::Find::name;
  (my $file2 = $file1) =~ s/^$directory1/$directory2/;

  my $mode1 = (stat($file1))[2] ;
  my $mode2 = (stat($file2))[2] ;

  my $uid1 = (stat($file1))[4] ;
  my $uid2 = (stat($file2))[4] ;

  print "Permissions for $file1 and $file2 are not the same\n" if ( $mode1 != $mode2 );
  print "Ownership for $file1 and $file2 are not the same\n" if ( $uid1 != $uid2 );
}
```

Look at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html for more info, particularly the `stat` one if you want to compare other file attributes.

If files don't exist in directory2 but exist in directory1, there will also be output because the `stat` will be different.

Comment: If you want the permission printed in UNIX-style, this comes in handy: `printf ("Permissions for %s and %s are not the same (%04o != %04o)\n", $file1, $file2, $mode1 &07777, $mode2 &07777) if ( $mode1 != $mode2);`

Comment: Another mod is to have, before the 'my $mode#...' lines `if (-e $file2) {` and following the print lines, add `} else { print "File $file2 does not exist"; }`. This is useful for avoiding permissions warnings for non-existent files.

Answer (score 13):

Find and stat:

`find . -exec stat --format='%n %A %U %G' {} \; | sort > listing`

Run that in both directories then compare the two listing files.

Saves you from the evils of Perl...

Comment: Then just diff the results :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you make sure the 2 folders should be the same recursively to some extent?
I think the `rsync` command is very powerful for that.

In your case you may run:

```
rsync  -n  -rpgov src_dir dst_dir  
(-n is a must otherwise dst_dir will be modified )
```

The different files or folders will be listed as the command output.

You can see the `man rsync` for a more complete explanation of these options.

Comment: using src_dir/ in stead of src_dir in the above command  will make its contents just be mapping to the dst_dir's contents )

Answer (score 1):

If the two directories have the same structure and you have `tree` installed, you could diff the directories by doing:

```
diff <(tree -ap parent_dir_1) <(tree -ap parent_dir_2)
```

Comment: Note that this solution will not show or catch changes in file ownership. For a complete solution, use `tree -agpu`.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` (or other shells supporting process substition using `<(…)`) using `find … -printf` (works using GNU `printf`):

```sh
diff -u \
  <(find path1/ -printf '%P %m\n' | sort) \
  <(find path2/ -printf '%P %m\n' | sort)
```

Answer (score -1):

`ls -al` will show the permissions, if both of them are in the same folder you will get something like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root 4096 nov 28 20:48 temp
drwxr-xr-x 2 lucas 1002 4096 mrt 24 22:33 temp2
```

The 3rd column is the owner, the 4th is the group.

Comment: Umm, what about the contents of temp and temp2?

Comment: two ways: open 2 shells go into both folders and do the same ls -al command, or 1 shell with tmux or just go into one folder do the command go into the other and do the same command again.

Comment: This solution will not scale.