# Copy file permissions, but not files in Unix

Tags: unix, file-permissions, unix-shell, copying

(From : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245144/copy-file-permissions-but-not-files, closed because off-topic)

I have two copies of the same directory tree. They almost have the same files in both (one version may have a couple extra or missing files). However, most of the files are in common to both directories (have the same relative paths and everything).

Assume these are in directories:

```
version1/
version2/
```

The problem is that the permissions in version1/ got messed up, and I would like to copy over the permissions from version2/, but do it without replacing the files in version1/ which are newer.

Is there an automated way to do this via shell commands or scripts?

Comment: Here there is a useful script in perl that you can use

http://serverfault.com/questions/373058/comparing-owners-and-permissions-of-content-of-two-folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I resolved by using "stat" command with "find" and "vi" to create a script that applies permissions.

```
cd version1/
find . -exec stat -c '%a %n' "{}" \; > setPerm.sh
vi setPerm.sh
```

Into "vi" I inserted into all the lines the "chmod" command: `%s/^/chmod /g`
I copied the script in `version2/` directory and executed it.

Other solutions seems valid but I do not tested them in case.

Answer (score 15):

GNU cp knows the `--attributes-only` flag since [coreutils 8.6](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=6553)

> --attributes-only   don't copy the file data, just the attributes

Comment: My version doesn't seem to have that flag, and some posts seem to have scary warnings [for example.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56792/how-to-copy-only-file-attributes-metadata-without-actual-content-of-the-file)

Answer (score 14):

My version of `cp` doesn't have the `--attributes-only` flag, so I worked up this. Briefly tested on simple folders, YMMV.

```
$> ls
version1/
version2/
$> ls -l version1/1/a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alex alex 0 Feb  5 12:49 version1/1/a
$> ls -l version2/1/a
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex 0 Feb  5 12:49 version1/1/a

$> find version1 -type f -printf '%P\n' | xargs -I {} \
    chmod --reference=version1/{} version2/{}

$> ls -l version2/1/a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alex alex 0 Feb  5 12:49 version1/1/a
```

Answer (score 5):

You can, but i don't think in an "automated way" !

GNU chown and GNU chmod have a `--reference=RFILE` parameter you can use.

```
chown --reference=RFILE yourfile
chmod --reference=RFILE yourfile
```

It uses `RFILE` settings (permissions, owner, group, etc..) and copies them to `yourfile`.

the manual explains in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Mariano Paniga's answer, I think I have a better one, that don't need to vi and search/replace commands. I'm even want to copy the ownership info too (uid/gid).

```
cd version1/
find . -exec stat -c 'chmod %a %n; chown %U:%G %n' "{}" \; > /tmp/setPerm.sh
chmod u+x /tmp/setPerm.sh
cd ../version2
/tmp/setPerm.sh
```

You may customize the commands inside `stat -c '...'` into anything you want. For all the available options, see `man stat`.

Comment: Does your script handle names with embedded newlines?

Comment: @deer-hunter It should work as-is, if not, you may add a quote ".." around the filename part.